# How to access the fields from the form data in symfony 3

Tags: symfony

I want to use how to access the username and password fields from the below code.

```
AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount Object
(
    [id:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => 
    [firstName:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => 
    [lastName:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => 
    [username:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => test
    [password:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => 123456
    [createdBy:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => 
    [updatedBy:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => 
    [createdAt:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => 
    [updatedAt:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => 
    [status:AppBundle\Entity\MasterUserAccount:private] => 
)

$data = $form->getData();

$username = $data['username'];
```

I'm getting the below error the following error

> Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\classname as array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` that you get out of a symfony form is an `Entity`. You can't access an attribute of this entity, as you do for arrays.

Instead you should be using getter method defined inside class `MasterUserAccount`.

So. It should be:

```
$username = $data -> getUserName();
```

This is assuming that getter method is already defined inside `MasterUserAccount` class. If not, create a getter method first.